# Possible use EBS + S3 with CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to put both my API server (ElasticBeanstalk) and static files server (S3) behind the same CloudFront. Such that

```
xxxxx.cloudfront.net -> S3 static website
xxxxx.cloudfront.net/api -> API Server
```

Isit possible? How do I do that? I tried setting up a new origin for the distribution but I dont think it works that way

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it works.  Create a new Cache Behavior to route specific path patterns to each origin.  Send `/api*` to this origin and send the default behavior to the bucket for everything else.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, yes figured I need that. But you want to add a answer for that? So I can mark it as answer? Also apart from docs, any recommended learning resource for these? How did you learn to configure cloudfront and AWS in general? In my case, it sometimes feels like its too much trial and error for more "complicated" stuff like these

Comment: Actually, there probably also is another problem with what you show, here.  Origin path should usually be left empty.  The AWS docs plus hands-on tinkering are my main learning resource, and are generally excellent, but I find that it's best to read them before you need them. Let me see what I can come up with for a useful answee.